# How to link a website on timeline card html template?

Tags: google-glass

Is it possible to have link on html template for google glass?

I want the user to tap on a link inside a timeline card and go to a website .

Thanks
Prem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't open a link that way directly what you can do is add an `OPEN_URI` menu item with the link as `payload` to your timeline card.

```
{
  "html": "(your card html code here)",
  "menuItems": [
    {
      "action": "OPEN_URI",
      "payload": "(your link here)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.action